# Accecss All Mail folder in GMAIL

Tags: email, jakarta-mail

Since there is no easy way to search in all folders, I was relying on fetching the emails from "All mail folder"

```
store.getFolder("[Gmail]/All Mail")
```

However, this breaks in international editions like Italian where All Mail is localized.

How do I get the "All Mail" folder for all international implementations?

Comment: If you have a question, you should ask it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Store.getFolder("[Gmail]").list().  On the returned Folders, cast them to IMAPFolder and use the [getAttributes method](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#getAttributes%28%29).  One of them should have a "\All" attribute.  See the [folderlist.java sample program](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples) for example code.